# Getting error while running go mod tidy like unable to connect to dev.azure.com?

Tags: git, azure, go

I am  running my project in  ubuntu 20.04 with wsl2.if we run go mod tidy from project repo then getting the error -go mod tidy

> go: dev.azure.com/abc/abc/_git/common.git@v0.0.0-20210319112308-ceb4f9ce35f8: invalid version: git fetch -f git://dev.azure.com/abc/abc/_git/common refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /home/name/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/6df6b6370763c12eca2ad232218f34099e8f5b956a0323787b3ae4f610e3fe8a: exit status 128:
> fatal: unable to connect to dev.azure.com:
> dev.azure.com[0: 13.107.42.20]: errno=Connection timed out

i will share the go env and git config result

```
GO111MODULE="on"


GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""


GOCACHE="/home/name/.cache/go-build"

GOENV="/home/name/.config/go/env"

GOEXE=""

GOFLAGS=""

GOHOSTARCH="amd64"

GOHOSTOS="linux"

GONOPROXY="dev.azure.com/abc/*"

GONOSUMDB="dev.azure.com/abc/*"

GOOS="linux"

GOPATH="/home/name/go"

GOPRIVATE="dev.azure.com/abc/*"

GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.13"

GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"

GOTMPDIR=""

GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.13/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"

GCCGO="gccgo"

AR="ar"

CC="gcc"

CXX="g++"

CGO_ENABLED="1"

GOMOD="/home/name/go/src/abc/go.mod"

CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_CPPFLAGS=""

CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"

CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"

PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"

GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build067756412=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"


cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
        name = name
        email = name@abc.com
        username = name
[url "https://abc:token@dev.azure.com"]
        insteadOf = https://dev.azure.com/


If anyone have idea then please help me on this?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cache is unreachable or corrupted. To clear the module cache `go clean -modcache` can help. See [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remove_object_files_and_cached_files)